# S3 operations with V4 authentication using Query parameter as Authentication method using AWS JAVA SDK

Tags: java, authentication, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to perform some S3 operations (like create bucket, get bucket, put object, list object etc) with V4 authentication using Query parameter as Authentication method.
I want to perform the operation using AWS JAVA SDKs

Question-
1. Does AWS JAVA SDK support Query parameter as Authentication method?If yes which package needs to be imported.
2. Any example of how to do that using AWS JAVA SDK will be greatly appreciated

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpJava.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/llJavaUploadFile.html

Comment: Hi Vicky, appreciate your reply, what i am looking for is performing S3 operations using Query parameter as Authentication method, the examples you shared will use HTTP Authorization header as Authentication method. Please refer this - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html#auth-methods-intro

Comment: So you want to calculate V4 authentication on your own?

Comment: I've code ready to calculate aws v4 signature in Java but I can't share its link because as per SO guidelines I'm not allowed to share my blog link.

Comment: I don't need code to calculate was v4 signature. What i want is sending the S3 requests using Query parameter as Authentication method. By default Authentication method is Authorization header & not Query parameter.I don't know how to send the requests using Query parameter as Authentication method

Answer (score 0):

You can generate pre-signed URL requests to access s3 resources using query parameter authentication.  Here's how to do it with the Java SDK:

```
URL url = s3Client.generatePresignedUrl(bucketName, key, expirationDate);
```

I've only used it successfully with GET requests.

Comment: Thanks for your time & reply, also wanted to know whether using query parameter authentication, have you created a bucket ? I don't know whether it is possible or not. If possible, any example will be greatly appreciated